# Boost tuple and stl vector compilation error

Tags: c++, boost

The following lines does not compile with error:

```
No viable overloaded '='



std::string myString;
float myFloat;
boost::tuple<const std::string&, float> myTuple 
    = boost::tuple<const std::string&, float>(myString, myFloat);
std::vector<boost::tuple<const std::string&, float> > myVector;
myVector.push_back(myTuple);
```

Does anybody has a clue !?
Hint: if I replace the "const std::string&" by a simple std::string, everything is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The members of a vector have to be copy assignable (C++98) or at least movable (C++11). A reference is not.

Comment: Here is the reason: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t650579-why-vector-needs-an-assignable-requirement-for-object-t.html